# Java 7: What charset shall I use when calling Files.newBufferedReader?

Tags: java, file-io, nio, java-7

In previous versions of Java, I would read a file by creating a buffered reader like this:

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file.txt"));
```

In Java 7, I would like to use [`Files.newBufferedReader`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#newBufferedReader%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.charset.Charset%29), but I need to pass in a charset as well. For example:

```
BufferedReader in = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get("file.txt"), 
                                            Charset.forName("US-ASCII"));
```

Previously, I did not have to worry about charsets when reading plain text files. What charset shall I use? Do you know what charset was used by default in previous versions of Java? I simply want to be able to find and replace the old statement with the new one.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Previously, I did not have to worry about charsets when reading plain text files.

Well, you should have done. If you were just using `FileReader`, it was using the default character encoding for the system. That was a bad idea, which is why I always used `FileInputStream` and an `InputStreamReader`. You should *always* be explicit about it. If you *really* want the default character encoding for the system, you should use [`Charset.defaultCharset()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html#defaultCharset%28%29) - but I strongly suggest that you don't.

If you're going to read a file, you should know the character encoding, and specify that. If you get to decide what character encoding to use when *writing* a file, UTF-8 is a good default choice.

Comment: Yes, I will do that going forward. (In my defence, none of the IO tutorials used a charset.) For now, I just want to upgrade my code such that all the files I was reading previously, continue to be read in the same way as they did before, without any unexpected results. Shall I use `defaultCharset()` then?

Comment: Yes, `defaultCharset()` will give you the previous behaviour. Just so long as you're aware that it's almost certainly not the right decision...

Answer (score 0):

`PrintWriter`/`PrintStream` in Java has by default [Charset.defaultCharset()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html#defaultCharset%28%29)

```
java.nio.charset.Charset.defaultCharset()
```

Comment: No, PrintWriter uses whatever the default character encoding has been determined as. On *some* systems that will be UTF-8, on others it will be something completely different.

Comment: oh sorry, my fault, that was not my intention, only want to say: use `defaultCharset()`